# How to set the JVM charset on the command line?

Tags: java, character-encoding, jvm

What's the command to set the JVM's character set?

(Also, what's the command to view the current JVM's character set, so I know how to reset it back to default after I'm done)

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

Java strings are always UTF-16 internally ([javadoc link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)), but you can use `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to facilitate reading files with a default charset.

Just ensure Java has access to that fileset when you set it or it won't start.

Comment: What's the full command? I'm running some maven unit tests. So `mvn -Dtest=MyTest -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 test`? That doesn't look right, does it?

Comment: @OneTwoThree That looks fine to me.

Comment: I tried the command to set the character set to latin1, but it didn't work. THe charset is still UTF-16

Comment: java's string encoding when stored in an internal variable will always be utf-16: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html, All the encoding does is help java read the binary from a file or input stream and convert it to utf-16.

Answer (score 0):

[java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset%28%29) Will get you the JVM's default charset.

Comment: But that wasn't the question.