# Specify the default file encoding in Java

Tags: java, powershell, encoding, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to run Java application (for which I have no sources) that reads files and handles them. Unfortunately, it can't handle files encoded in UTF-8.

Using [JD](http://jd.benow.ca/) I've seen the function `Files.readAllLines` fails with an UnmappableCharacterException. While it's possible to provide a Charset to the function, since I don't have the source code to the application, I can't change it.

So I want to tell Java to use UTF-8 as the default character set. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10890594/871910) explains that I should add `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to the command line. However, when I type:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar <my jar> <arguments>
```

I get an error saying `.encoding=UTF-8` cannot be found as a main class.

I know I'm missing something stupid, but I can't find what it is...

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't it. UTF-8 works. I'm keeping this question in case someone else encounters this unexpected PowerShell behvaior.

Comment: Added the powershell tag because this was the actual cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I *was* missing something stupid.

I'm using PowerShell. PowerShell treats `-` in a special way. I had to write

```
java "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" -jar ...
```

And now everything is running fine.

Stupid PowerShell.

Comment: or `-D"file.encoding=UTF-8"`